# Using to upper incorrectly? Working code until I entered toupper

Tags: c++, toupper

My program worked like it was supposed to until I added the toupper part into my program. I've tried looking at my error code but it's not really helping. The errors are:

> no matching function to call
>   2 arguments expected, one provided

So I know the error is in those two statements in my while loop. What did I do wrong?

I want to make a name like

> john brown
>   go to
>   John Brown

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  string firstname[5];
  string lastname[5];
  ifstream fin( "data_names.txt" );
  if (!fin) {
    cout << "There is no file" << endl;
  }
  int i = 0;
  while( i < 5 && (fin >> firstname[i]) && (fin >> lastname[i]) ) {
    firstname[0] = toupper(firstname[0]);
    lastname[0] = toupper(lastname[0]);
    i++;
  }
  cout << firstname[0] << " " << lastname [0] << endl;
  cout << firstname[1] << " " << lastname [1] << endl;
  cout << firstname[2] << " " << lastname [2] << endl;
  cout << firstname[3] << " " << lastname [3] << endl;
  cout << firstname[4] << " " << lastname [4] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: `toupper` expects an `int` you're passing it a `string` - [`toupper` Documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/).

Comment: `toupper` works on a single character at a time. If you want to upper-ize a whole string you need to make a loop that goes through the string applying `toupper` to each character

Comment: @M.M I want to only uppercase those two letters. How do I highlight those characters of the string and do it correctly?

Comment: @JOHNSMITH8338 which two letters?

Answer (score 3):

[`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) works on individual characters, but you are trying to apply it to strings.  Besides adding `#include <cctype>`, you need to modify your `while` loop's body:

```
firstname[i][0] = toupper(firstname[i][0]);
lastname[i][0] = toupper(lastname[i][0]);
i++;
```

Then it should work as expected.  [Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bf11c1982008331)

As M.M helpfully pointed out in the comments, you should also check that your strings aren't empty before accessing their first characters, i.e. something like

```
if (!firstname[i].empty()) firstname[i][0] = toupper(...);
```

is strongly recommended.

Mind you, you will probably need more sophisticated logic if you get names like `McDonald` :)

Comment: Technically it should be either `toupper( (unsigned char)firstname[i][0] );` (with cctype included), or `toupper( firstname[i][0], std::locale() )`  . Also it'd be good to check that the string is not empty for doing `[0]`

Comment: @M.M I agree. The question's code could benefit from a much more general review.

Comment: @mindriot Sorry, I missed the part about including `cctype`.

Comment: @juanchopanza actually, looks like `cctype` is not even strictly necessary ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f516162145507d1)), it seems to get pulled in by one of the other headers anyway.

Comment: @mindriot Yeah, but that can't be relied upon. BTW that's how the other overload gets pulled in.

Comment: @JOHNSMITH8338 did this answer your question? If so, you may accept the answer. If not, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You need ctype.h to get the proper definition for `toupper()`.  It is usually implemented not as a function, but an array mapping.

```
 #include <ctype.h>
```

---

The program has several flaws:  using a string array instead of a string, not iterating through the string correctly, not declaring but using the C definition of toupper(), not exiting when the file does not exist.

Use this instead:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  ifstream fin ("data_names.txt");
  if (!fin) 
  {
    cerr << "File missing" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  // not sure if you were trying to process 5 lines or five words per line
  // but this will process the entire file
  while (!fin.eof())
  {
       string s;
       fin >> s;
       for (i = 0;  i < s.length();  ++i)
            s [i] = toupper (s [i]);
       cout << s << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe it's usually implemented as a function these days, because so many people call it passing plain `char` as argument (which breaks on the array implementation)

Comment: BTW, the C++ header would be `cctype`, then use `std::toupper`.

Comment: @juanchopanza won't OP's code still produce errors when not using the 2 parameter C++ overload, since he's passing a `string` when an `int` is expected?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yes, it will. That will be a different error.

Comment: @juanchopanza what is the correct way to do so? I changed it to:

 l=lastname[0];
    putchar (toupper(l));
    f=firstname[0];
    putchar (toupper(f));
    i++;
but still am getting an error.

Comment: @M.M:  The original Unix 7 implementation (I think) declared both a function (for function pointer use) and a macro which might expand, depending on implementation to a tertiary evaluation or a mapping array.

Comment: @JOHNSMITH8338:  What is the exact error text you get?

Comment: @JOHNSMITH8338 Unclear what you're really trying to do but `lastname[0]` is an `std::string`. To get its first character you'd need `lastname[0][0]`. No idea why you're using an array of strings.

Comment: @juanchopanza My project is to read in full names from a file and then print them into two separate arrays. I want to make john brown to John Brown. I believe I have to use strings.

Comment: @JOHNSMITH8338:  Yes, use a `string`, not a string array `string[5]`.

Comment: @wallyk he said the code was working properly without `toupper` which suggests the intent is to read 5 pairs of names from the file  .  (Of course an output loop would be better, but that's another issue)

Comment: @juanchopanza: There may be some parts that are correct, but I also see a `while (!fin.eof())`...

Comment: @JerryCoffin:  Oh yeah, I meant to look that up.

Comment: @wallyk: There are a few other things to fix as well. For one, `toupper` can only deal with positive numbers + EOF, but in many character sets, accented characters (and such) will be negative when viewed as `char`s.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ha! That was added after my votes and discussions. The original had no code.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ah, I see--I have to admit, I was a bit surprised, but I didn't think to look through the edit history and compare time stamps. My bad (as they say).